# Como recorrer JSON con AJAX

Tags: ajax, json

**Tengo el siguiente JSON** :

```
{"success":"true","data":{"usuarios":{"iduser":114,"cuenta":"arieldiaz"}}}
```

**y mi ajax es el siguiente:**

```
success: function(response){
    if (response.success) {
        $.each(response.data.usuarios, function( key, value ) { 
            $.each( value, function (trkey,trvalue) {
                switch(trkey){ 
                    case 'iduser':
                    alert(trvalue);
                    break;
                }
            });
        });       
    }
}
```

> El problema es que no toma el valor del json(iduser)

Comment: te bota algun error?, si es asi muestralo para saber cual es

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas el segundo `$.each()`.  El primero ya itera por los usuarios, solo debes de desplegar lo que quieres.  Algo asi:

```js
var response = {"success":"true","data":{"usuarios":{"iduser":114,"cuenta":"arieldiaz"}}};


var success = function(response){
    if (response.success) {
        $.each(response.data.usuarios, function( key, value ) {             
                switch(key){ 
                    case 'iduser':
                    alert(value);
                    break;
                }           
        });       
    }
};

success(response);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```